# Rest API call works with curl but doesn't work with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, rest, curl, dynamics-crm, bearer-token

I have following `curl` request that works

`curl.exe -X GET "https://host.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/accounts?$select=name" -H "Authorization: Bearer xxxxx"`

And want to implement it in PowerShell

```
Invoke-RestMethod "https://host.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/accounts?`$select=name" `
                    -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer xxxxx"} `
                    -Method  Get
```

I've also tried to do request with `Invoke-WebRequest` as well as `curl` version in Powershell and it didn't work

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
At E:\Repos\myrepo\host\connection_test.ps1:51 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod $hostName `
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When making connection using Invoke-RestMethod, you want to make sure that encryption your client is using is accepted by the URI.

PowerShell by default uses TLS 1.0 for web requests but the URI you are connecting to probably uses 1.1 or 1.2. You can use the following to force the use of TLS v1.1 or v1.2.

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = `
    [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls11, [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12;
Invoke-RestMethod "https://host.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/accounts?`$select=name" `
                -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer xxxxx"} `
                -Method  Get
```